# Finding Global Inverse of $ f(x,y,z)= \left( \frac{x}{a+x+y+z}, \frac{y}{a+x+y+z}, \frac{z}{a+x+y+z} \right).$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $a\neq 0$, and $E=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:a+x+y+z\neq 0\}$ and $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by

$$ f(x,y,z)= \left( \frac{x}{a+x+y+z}, \frac{y}{a+x+y+z}, \frac{z}{a+x+y+z} \right).$$

Compute the inverse of $f$.

---

I know I can use the Inverse Function Theorem to show local invertibility, however, that does not necessarily imply global invertibility. Thus, even though I can invert the Jacobian of the function, it does not follow that I can recover the inverse function from its Jacobian. Therefore, I have no idea what to try for this problem. Could you please provided a small hint on something to try for this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985671/proving-fx-y-z-big-fracxaxyz-fracyaxyz-fraczaxyz), too. So Joe Man Analysis=Gaby Boy Analysis.

Comment: Joe Man Analysis = Gaby Boy Analysis

Comment: @user982787 We're actually not. We are friends in real life though.

Comment: @AndrewLi Why would they be duplicates? My question is related to finding the inverse of the function given above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve the equation $f(x, y, z) = (u, v, w)$ for $(x, y, z)$, add the three components and conclude that
$$
 \frac{x+y+z}{a+x+y+z} = u+v+w \implies a+x+y+z = \frac{a}{1-(u+v+w)} \, .
$$
Then view at $f(x, y, z) = (u, v, w)$ again.